# Using %w with runtime input

Tags: ruby, arrays, string, words

I'm trying to use `%w` with a string input at run time. When I run this program:

```
a = gets.chomp
puts %w(a).count
```

with the input `'hi how are you'`, the output is `1`. `%w(a).count` doesn't replace `a` with the input string.

While `%w(hi how are you).length` is `4`, `%w(a)` treats `a` as a single entity and its `count` value is `1`.

How can I print the length `4` or any number for a string that is input at run time?

Comment: Problem is `%w('hi hello').size`  gives `2`. But..`s = gets.chomp` and `%W(#{str}).size` gives `1`. This is **strange**. Your one is giving correct result... `%w(str)` means simply `['str']`.. `%W` does *interpolation*, but `%w` doesn't. But here *interpolation* trick didn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `String#split`.

For Example:

```
a = "hi how are you"
a.split(" ").size
```

Comment: This code is not equivalent to what you would get if a string were expanded n `%w`.

Answer (score 0):

Although `%W` does interpolation (`%w` does not), it does *not* behave like a literal string with `split`. You can see an example in [this blog post](http://t-a-w.blogspot.co.il/2010/07/another-example-of-ruby-being-awesome-w.html):

> And I thought I was also aware of `%W` - which obviously would work
>   just like `%w` except evaluating code inside. Except that's not what
>   it does! `%W[foo #{bar}]` is not `"foo #{bar}".split` - it's `["foo", "#{bar}"]`! 
>   And using a real parser of course, so you can use as many
>   spaces inside that code block as you want.
>
> ```
> system *%W[mongod --shardsvr --port #{port} --fork --dbpath #{data_dir}
> --logappend --logpath #{logpath} --directoryperdb]
> ```

So in your case:

```
a = 'hi how are you'
%W(#{a})
# => ["hi how are you"]
```

So your count will still be `1`.

The proper way to get `4` is to use `split`...

Comment: Thanks for your answer and for some detailed explanation. I could search for the meaning of the word interpolation from this [link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable_interpolation). But I don't really have much idea on what does extrapolation mean, could you please share an example on this or point me to some documentation ?